# Change the cursor to zoom in and zoom out symbol

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to change the cursor point to zoom in and zoom out symbol.

I know how to change the cursor to busy, wait and etc,

```
document.manual_production.style.cursor='wait';
```

but I don't know how to change the cursor to that for zooming in and out.

I got it by this way

```
document.manual_production.image1.style.cursor='-moz-zoom-out';
```

Answer (score 4):

And for Chrome/Safari/WebKit, there is `cursor: -webkit-zoom-in` and `cursor: -webkit-zoom-out`.

Answer (score 3):

Your going to need a cur icon for that:

```
document.manual_production.style.cursor = 'url(/path/to/mycursor.cur) 0 0, pointer';
```

Comment: what is the path this " /path/to/mycursor.cur"

Comment: document.manual_production.image1.style.cursor='-moz-zoom-out';

Answer (score 1):

What @sheeks06 is saying is that you need to upload your own cursor image. Google for 'free cursors', wade through the heaps of idiotic animated cursors until you find one you need, upload it to your web server.

url(/path/to/mycursor.cur) means the place you uploaded your cursor.

-moz-zoom will only work in Mozilla Firefox, not in most other browsers.

Comment: I had the feeling the asker might need some extra info, based on his question/comments :P